# Ember external js and global

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

In my Ember app I am trying to add the [money.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/) external lib. I successfully achieved that by installing it with bower and then adding `app.import('bower_components/money.js/money.js');` to my *ember-cli-build.js*.

money.js defines a global variable `fx` which is available all over my app. However I receive many JSHint Errors while building the app like:

`components/purchase-form.js: line 41, col 29, 'fx' is not defined.`

[Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html) states:

> Typically, the application object is the only global variable. All
>   other classes in your app should be properties on the
>   Ember.Application instance, which highlights its first role: a global
>   namespace.

I just wonder what is the proper way to import this kind of lib along with its global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `app.import` a global you have to possibilities to make jsHint happy:

1. Adding `/* global fx */` before accessing the global per file.
2. Adding it to `predefs` section in `.jshintrc` as @kumkanillam mentioned in his answer.

If you don't like to access dependency as a global you could shim it. Ember-cli provides a vendor-shim generator: `ember generate vendor-shim money.js` Afterward you could use `import` in your modules.

This topic is well-documented in [ember-cli docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#standard-non-amd-asset).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid jsHint error, you can mention `fx` global variable

```
{
  "predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise",
    "fx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: good to know and I'll use it but my question need a more exhaustive answer. tnx

Comment: @masciugo This answer is adequate. The only problem is a linting warning, because you're using a global (`fx`) that is not defined in the scope of the file.

Comment: kumkanillam said something true and was helpful but I asked __what is the proper way to import this kind of lib along with its global__. I ended up using  the shim.